# Apache package in cygwin does not seem to work. Error logs are also empty

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cygwin, apache-http-server

I installed `cygwin` in a `Windows` pc. All ok.
Then I tried to install `apache` package. I selected all relevant packages and installed them as well.
The problem: In `/usr/sbin` I can see `apachectl2` and `http2` and also I can see the configuration files under `/etc/apache2` e.g the `httpd.conf` it does not seem to work.
There is no `www` directory under `/var`. I created one in case and also a subdirectory named `cgi-bin` i.e. I created `www/cgi-bin` and placed a sample `.pl` script but it does not work.
I can not even connect to the main apache page i.e. in `http://localhost:9080` (I put `9080` in the `httpd.conf`).
The `/var/log/apache2/error_log` is empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
I see in various sources that somehow `cygserver` is a prerequisite. I see an advice that a `CYGWIN` env var should exist that should contain the word `server`. Have no idea what this means.

**UPDATE 2:**
Following this [example](http://victormiti.umusebo.com/blog/installing-and-configuring-apache-php-mysql-on-cygwin) I installed cygserver as a service. This seem to go ok.
Also I tried to install `ssh` (not sure why) and run `httpd2.conf`. These failed to install:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I have been trying this from yesterday. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 3**
For some reason *sometimes* the apache service starts!

[image]

When I type `localhost:8085` (I changed the port in `httpd2.conf` to be `8085` the browser just hangs. I get no response and the page seems to be in some kind of loading state as if trying to establish connection

**UPDATE 3**
In the `/var/log/apache2/error_log` now I see:

```
[Sun May 19 15:03:10 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
      2       2 [main] httpd2 1684 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap mod_dir.so to same address as parent (002D0000) - try running rebaseall
      3 fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
      4 unable to fork new process
      5 [Sun May 19 15:07:22 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
      6 [Sun May 19 15:07:23 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
      7 [Sun May 19 15:07:23 2013] [notice] Digest: done
      8       2 [main] httpd2 2908 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
      9 [Sun May 19 15:07:23 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     10 [Sun May 19 15:07:33 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
     11       3 [main] httpd2 1692 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_status.so' (0x3A0000) is already occupied
     12 [Sun May 19 15:07:34 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     13       2 [main] httpd2 5952 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
     14 [Sun May 19 15:07:45 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     15       3 [main] httpd2 624 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_status.so' (0x3A0000) is already occupied
     16 [Sun May 19 15:07:55 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     17       3 [main] httpd2 5008 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
     18 [Sun May 19 15:08:06 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     19       2 [main] httpd2 2952 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-4-2.dll' (0x2A0000) is already occupied
     20 [Sun May 19 15:08:16 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     21       4 [main] httpd2 4148 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
     22 [Sun May 19 15:08:26 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     23       3 [main] httpd2 1660 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_status.so' (0x3A0000) is already occupied
     24 [Sun May 19 15:08:36 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     25      71 [main] httpd2 5756 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap cygldap-2-3-0.dll to same address as parent (004D0000) - try running rebaseall
     26 [Sun May 19 15:08:47 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     27       3 [main] httpd2 3496 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap mod_mime.so to same address as parent (002B0000) - try running rebaseall
     28 [Sun May 19 15:08:57 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     29       2 [main] httpd2 568 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
     30 [Sun May 19 15:09:07 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     31       2 [main] httpd2 5640 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-4-2.dll' (0x2A0000) is already occupied
     32 [Sun May 19 15:09:17 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     33       3 [main] httpd2 5764 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap cygldap-2-3-0.dll to same address as parent (004D0000) - try running rebaseall
     34 [Sun May 19 15:09:27 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     35       3 [main] httpd2 5992 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-4-2.dll' (0x2A0000) is already occupied
     36 [Sun May 19 15:09:37 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     37       3 [main] httpd2 2956 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-3-0.dll' (0x550000) is already occupied
     38 [Sun May 19 15:09:40 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     39       3 [main] httpd2 5040 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_mime.so' (0x2B0000) is already occupied
     40 [Sun May 19 15:09:50 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     41 [Sun May 19 15:10:00 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
     42 [Sun May 19 15:10:00 2013] [notice] seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
     43 [Sun May 19 15:13:22 2013] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
     44 [Sun May 19 15:13:23 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
     45 [Sun May 19 15:13:23 2013] [notice] Digest: done
     46       2 [main] httpd2 2536 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     47 [Sun May 19 15:13:23 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     48 [Sun May 19 15:13:33 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.1e DAV/2 configured -- resuming normal operations
     49       4 [main] httpd2 5896 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     50 [Sun May 19 15:13:34 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     51       2 [main] httpd2 988 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     52 [Sun May 19 15:13:45 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     53       3 [main] httpd2 5296 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_status.so' (0x3D0000) is already occupied
     54 [Sun May 19 15:13:55 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     55       2 [main] httpd2 4828 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     56 [Sun May 19 15:14:06 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     57       2 [main] httpd2 2188 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     58 [Sun May 19 15:14:16 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     59       2 [main] httpd2 1664 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mod_imagemap.so' (0xC60000) is already occupied
     60 [Sun May 19 15:14:26 2013] [error] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: fork: Unable to fork new process
     61       2 [main] httpd2 5212 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'cyglber-2-4-2.dll' (0x3B0000) is already occupied
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/cygwin.html?

Comment: @boot13:No I haven't thank you for the link.There is no `apache_1.3.x` in my installation though

Answer (score 1):

The error message contains the answer (emphasis mine):

```
2 [main] httpd2 1684 child_info_fork::abort: unable to remap mod_dir.so to same address as parent (002D0000) - **try running rebaseall**
```

This is answered in the official [Cygwin FAQ](http://cygwin.com/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures).

Comment: Could a rebaseall corrupt my installation?

Comment: `rebaseall` is a safe procedure and usually fixes `fork(2)` errors such as these.  If that doesn't help, it may be a [BLODA](http://cygwin.com/faq/faq.using.html#faq.using.bloda) problem.